# Python generator of generator

Tags: python, generator

Here's a problem I get on an interview (python 3.7):

```
def add(x,y):
    return x+y

g = (x for x in range(4))
for n in [1,10]:
    g = (add(n,i) for i in g)
list(g)
```

What does list(g) print? Answer is

```
20,21,22,23
```

From the output, I guess what happened is the add function looped twice, and both of the time n=10? Can someone explain to me what happens step by step? I am so confused. Much thanks.

Comment: If you want to understand the code step-by-step why not use a debugger or [PythonTutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) instead of asking here? Also read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 3):

The "body" of a generator expression does not capture values in a closure, so `n` is just a free variable whose value is whatever is assigned to `n` once `g` is evaluated. (The expression iterated over is, so `g` is not a free variable, but the iterable currently assigned to `g`.)

That is, after `for` loop, you have

```
assert n == 10  # The last value assigned to n

# Pseudocode - every time n is used, it resolves to the *current*
# value of n, not the value n had when the generator expression was 
# defined.
g = (add(10, i) for i in (add(10, i) for i in (x for x in range(4))))
#  *not* (add(10, i) for i in (add(1, i) for i in (x for x in range(4))))
  = (add(10, i) for i in (add(10, i) for i in (0, 1, 2, 3)))
  = (add(10, i) for i in (10, 11, 12, 13))
  = (10 + i for i in (10, 11, 12, 13)
```

And so

```
list(g) == [20, 21, 22, 23]
```

Comment: Why isn't it `(add(n, i) for i in (add(n, i) for i in (add(n, i) ...)))`…?

Comment: @deceze Not sure I understand the question, but `n` was drawn over a list of 2 elements, not a 10-element range, if you are asking about the depth of nesting.

Comment: Woops, total blackout there between `[1,10]` and `range(1, 10)`. My bad.

Comment: @deceze I made the same mistake initially :)

Answer (score 1):

Because `g` is *generator object*.

Unlike *listcomp* which is calculated *immediately*, it's just a generator *instance* waiting to be iterated.

```py
>>> from inspect import getgeneratorstate
>>> g = (x for x in range(4))
>>> getgeneratorstate(g)
'GEN_CREATED'

>>> next(g)
0
>>> getgeneratorstate(g)
'GEN_SUSPENDED'

>>> list(g)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> getgeneratorstate(g)
'GEN_CLOSED'
```

However, reference to first generator `(x for x in range(4))` does not change inside generator object. Because `g` is just a reference on a object on memory.

> Name is merely a post-it on a box. - Fluent Python.
>
> [image: Fluent Python]

So when we pass `g`, mere memory address of referencing object is passed, not `g` itself. Therefore, in following case:

```
>>> g = (x for x in range(4))
>>> g
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x036babbc>

>>> g = (add(n, i) for i in g)
```

`g` inside generator expression `(add(n, i) for i in g)` is merely passing mem-address `0x036babbc` to expression, and generator *instance* created from that expression remembers that address, so even if `g` is redeclared that does not affect already created generator instances.

So in sequenece:

```
>>> g = (x for x in range(4))
>>> g
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0452c22c>  # 1

>>> g = (add(10, i) for i in g)
>>> g
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x044ee178>  # 2
>>> g.gi_frame.f_locals['.0']
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0452c22c>  # 1 stored

>>> g = (add(10, i) for i in g)
>>> g
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x03bd88c8>  # 3
>>> g.gi_frame.f_locals['.0']
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x044ee178>  # 2 stored
```

As you see, each generator expressions remembers last referenced generator *instances*, so it's keep getting nested.